# Video in a virtual machine?

Tags: c++, c, video, virtual-machine

I'm currently building a simple virtual machine and I'm wondering about how to work with video. Since a traditional console wouldn't work, would SDL or OpenGL work? How would I be able to control pixel per pixel and create video memory around it?

Comment: [aalib](http://aa-project.sourceforge.net/aalib/) can display videos just fine on a traditional console, if you provide the appropriate decoding logic.

Comment: Unclear. Are you writing your own VM (like Hyper-V/VMWare) or writng VM in Java sense or trying to see if it is possible to use video related API in existing VMs?

Comment: I'm writing my own VM (16bit) from scratch. Right now I have all the CPU stuff working and was wondering about video.

Comment: Still not exactly clear: are you writing a VMM (ie hypervisor) or a simple OS that runs inside of virtual machine?

Comment: more of an emulation virtual machine. It's a bytecode VM that's just being interpreted atm.

Comment: In this [Basic tutorial of SDL](http://www.sdltutorials.com/sdl-tutorial-basics) you can start drawing, even pixel by pixel. [Here](http://www.cpp-home.com/tutorials/154_1.htm) you can check some codes of drawing pixels